# Why is google talk plugin video accelerator crashing on startup?

Tags: optimus, browser-plugin

I believe this problem could happen to any linux installation with the google-talkplugin and NVidia optimus, but I'll post my system specs just in case anyone is wondering:
Fedora 18, 64 bits, Dell XPS 15z **WITH** optimus technology.

I installed the plugin when entering my first google plus hangout session. The installation seemed fine ( I had no error during or after package installation) until I got the message "the following plug-in has crashed: Google Talk Plugin Video Accelerator" when I opened the hangout session.
I also tried Firefox, with the same result. (The error message was a bit different: "The google talk Video Accelerator plugin has crashed")

I did enable the plugin to be ran automatically in chrome, since all others are blocked and only run when I request.

What can be done to get the hangout working?

Answer (score 0):

After searching extensively and reinstalling the plugin following several different sets of instructions, I stumbled on [this littled closed thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/iWNMOeiKXcQ).

The solution was simple: open chrome using `optirun`. (you first have to close any "chromes" you may have open, otherwise the command line call to open a new window will just add one to the already running chrome execution, the one using the default intel driver).

It seems the problem is OpenGL. The intel driver I have (the default Fedora 18 driver) doesn't seem capable of handling the plugin, but NVidia's proprietary driver handles it just fine. I am not sure about this explanation though.